# HTML5 form validations are not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form in which, when I focus on username, entire form should popout, so I did the following code which works fine.

```
<p style="background: none; font-weight: bold; color: red;">
    <strong>Admission Enquiry:</strong> <input type="text" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Your Name">
</p>

<form class="col-md-4 input-form" id="form" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" name="name" required> <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email"
        id="email" name="email" required> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" id="phone" name="phone" required> <select
        class="form-control" name="options" id="options" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <option selected>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-submit">
</form>
```

Jquery code

```
$('.input-field').focus(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.input-form').css({
        display : 'block'
    });
});
```

This does what is required, but i am not able to get the form validations such as `required`,`email`,`pattern` to work. It does not do any validations when I press submit button without entering the required fields, als it displays error in console `An invalid form control with name='name' is not focusable.` Is there any workaround?

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bjcf412n/1/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nfq1L7y0/

Comment: Clear your cache (Ctrl+F5) and try again.

Comment: Sorry, the form is initially hidden using display:none, and when the textbox is on focus, it pops out.